# Fix 'Your SIM cannot be registered' problem with Moto G2 on Android Marshmallow

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, sim-card, motorola-moto-g2

I have Moto G 2nd Generation mobile with Android 6.0 Marshmallow. The problem is suddenly one day, one of my SIM doesn't get signal at all.

I tried:

- Settings > More > Cellular Networks > Connect automatically, then a prompt saying "Your SIM cannot be registered" or "Cannot connect to this network right now. Please try again later"
- Selecting manually the network that my SIM belongs to. This time the prompt is "No Service Selected network unavailable"
- Removing SIM and inserting in another slot, rebooted, turned on airplane mode and off, etc. but nothing worked
- Dialing `*#*#4636#*#*` and did "Turn off radio" and also selected "GSM only", "GSM auto(PRL)", "WCDMA only", etc. but nothing helped
- Factory reset, even this doesn't work

If I insert this SIM in another mobile, it works. And other SIMs work fine on my mobile. This issue is not there in the beginning and I remember I did not install anything new or change a setting.

I couldn't get a solution even on the community or on Google. Please do help me.

Additional info:

- Device model: Moto G2 (XT1068)
- Android version: 6.0 Marshmallow
- Problematic SIM: BSNL

Comment: Is this problem only at a given location ( = could be cell tower congestion ) or is it in any / many locations?

Comment: No this is not a location problem because the SIM works in other mobiles

Comment: This seems to be BSNL specific. 1. Try to set *Preferred network type* in *different* options available like 2G/ 3G/ WCDMA ( try all) , whatever is available in your phone, Reboot and see 2. If that doesn't help, get your SIM replaced from BSNL- it could be SIM card problem (contacts with hardware not properly connecting) I had an Airtel card that died like this .

Comment: Here is a page with a person with a very similar issue and they have 2 proposed solutions.  See if either listed helps you: http://thewichitacomputerguy.com/blog/how-i-fixed-your-sim-card-does-not-allow-connection-network-g1

Comment: Also, SIM cards are very very sensitive so even if you carefully swap this card between devices that can easily cause damage, and also static eletricity (100 volts is enough to hurt electronics, and you would never even feel that passing between you and the card).  So you may need to grab a new SIM card (I mean even reading/writing info to them exhausts them quickly and is why Android stopped writing contact info to SIMs in version 2).

Answer (score 0):

I did some searching and it appears this is not restricted to yourself.  I mean if it works in another device (with full BSNL functionality) then you have limited the problem to this specific device.  I found the following page from a Moto G User which may still apply for you if you would like to give it a shot:

http://www.techulator.com/resources/12632-Moto-G-not-recognizing-the-SIM-How-to-solve-SIM-problems.aspx

I am also wondering did you try to remove the SIM from the slot it is not working in plug it in to the slot it is not normally in and REBOOT the phone and see if you have it fully working.  If this is the case then it is probably an issue with Marshmallow recognizing the second slot which from looks of google search seems to be an issue they encountered when Lollipop upgrades first hit too.

Comment: Could always take the phone with you to a store and explain the SIM is not working and have them insert a brand new one there in the store and test it.  If that works then you could just use that as it is rare but maybe there is a defect on the SIM the other mobiles can get past while the G2 can not for some reason (crazy things happen some times).